# Object detection model on custom dataset

Tags: yolov8

Is there any model that we can use for object detection entirely on our custom dataset?, Because while working with yolov8 as it is already trained on COCO dataset, so its not performing well with my custom dataset.

I have also used transfer learning as well as sequential training of yolov8 training on my data, but still unable to get results.